# Numpy destroys PIL TiffImageFile's tile attribute

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, tiff

I'm opening a url to an image, and then opening the image using PIL's `Image.open` method.  When a convert the PIL TiffImageFile to a numpy array, the PIL TiffImageFile's tile attribute is lost.

Why is this happening?

Am I making a mistake?

Here is example code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

url = "https://some_url_to_tiff_file"
img = Image.open(urlopen(url))
#If I call img.tile here, the info shows.
img_np = np.asarray(img)
#img_np = np.array(img) also causes a problem
#If I call img.tile here, the list is empty.
```

Comment: Probably because a URL doesn't support `seek`. Try reading the URL into a `BytesIO` object and using that.

Comment: The same thing occurs when a local file is used instead of a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue in [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow)'s code.  The method `TiffImageFile._load_libtiff` executes the line [`self.tile = []`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/a656a0bd603bcc333184ad1baf61d118925b3772/src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py#L1162).  That method is called when `np.array(img)` or `np.asarray(img)` is called because numpy accesses the `__array_interface__` property, and the implementation of that property calls `self.tobytes()`, which calls `self.load()`, and in a `TiffImageFile` instance, that leads to the call to `self._load_libtiff()`.

The `tile` attribute can be unexpectedly clobbered without the use of numpy.  For example,

```
In [25]: img = Image.open('foo.tiff')

In [26]: img.tile
Out[26]: [('tiff_lzw', (0, 0, 499, 630), 0, ('RGB', 'tiff_lzw', False))]

In [27]: img2 = img.convert(mode='RGB')

In [28]: img.tile
Out[28]: []
```

The first line of the `convert` docstring is "Returns a converted copy of this image", so it is surprising that the method changes the `tile` attribute.  I'd call that a Pillow bug, but maybe there is a good reason for that side effect.